# Pytest: patching the function invoked in another task

Tags: mocking, pytest, python-asyncio, python-unittest, patch

I have code as follows:

```
import asyncio
import pytest

from unittest.mock import patch


def another_func():
    pass

class A:
    async def func(self):
        print(f"!!!!!!!!!!!{another_func}!!!!!!!!!!!")
        another_func()
        
    async def run(self):
        await self.func()
        asyncio.create_task(self.func())
        


@pytest.mark.asyncio
@patch("main.another_func")
async def test_otg_test_low_disk_space_handler_fired(patched):
    a = A()
    await a.run()
```

The result output looks as follows:

```
main.py !!!!!!!!!!!<MagicMock name='another_func' id='139827220171360'>!!!!!!!!!!!
!!!!!!!!!!!<function another_func at 0x7f2c0fdfd2d0>!!!!!!!!!!!
```

I wonder if there is a way to properly patch the `another_func` to see the `MagicMock` also as the second output as well. I think, `asyncio.create_task` somehow "forgets" to take the mocks and patches inside its execution context.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the answer is named `monkeypatch`. This guy finally allowed me to mock the function even in another task. Finding solution took me half a day, so I leave it here for anyone needed.

The working code is as follows:

```
import asyncio
import pytest

from unittest.mock import MagicMock


def another_func():
    pass

class A:
    async def func(self):
        print(f"!!!!!!!!!!!{another_func}!!!!!!!!!!!")
        another_func()
        
    async def run(self):
        await self.func()
        asyncio.create_task(self.func())
        


@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_func(monkeypatch):
    a = A()
    mock = MagicMock()
    monkeypatch.setattr("main.another_func", mock)
    await a.run()
```

and the awaited result is as follows:

```
main.py !!!!!!!!!!!<MagicMock id='139952231369168'>!!!!!!!!!!!
!!!!!!!!!!!<MagicMock id='139952231369168'>!!!!!!!!!!!
```